# Should I use wouldn't or didn't?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

> The only person I called was my best friend, and in her effort to take me out of my state of shock, she suggested that I visit her so that I didn’t fall on old grief patterns she’s seen me through before.

Should I have use wouldn’t instead of didn’t? Should I not use the word fall. I just am not sure if this sentence is proper English.

Answer (score -2):

1. It's a very long sentence. I would break it up into more than one and add a comma before the last part of it.
2. I think you mean **fall back on** instead of "fall on." **Revert to** would also be a good choice.

> The only person I called was my best friend. In her effort to take me out of my state of shock, she suggested I visit her, so that I didn't fall back on old grief patterns she's seen me through before.

Comment: Instead of downvoting me, why not suggest a better answer?